# How to suggest a new best answer?

Tags: feature-request, flags, answers, voting, accepted-answer

How to suggest a new correct answer **to the question owner** when anotherone is already marked as best answer?

For example in "[Get PHP session vars in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342509/get-php-session-vars-in-htaccess/)" 
according to the comments made by the community Tom Haigh's answer is the correct answer despite less votes nevertheless there is no way to flag it as "new best answer".

I understand that flags are made for "negative" observations but I suggest new features to be able to give a positive feedback about an answer **in addition to the up vote**.

Comment: Checkmark doesn't indicate best, it just indicates that the OP has selected it as the most helpful to them. The best answer usually has the most upvotes (given time), to "suggest" a new best answer you upvote it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I understand your point. So if we can up/down vote answer why can't we positively/negatively flag an answer? Otherways no need to flag an answer as irrelevant just vote it down...

Comment: There is no such thing as positively flagging. Flagging is always for negative stuff.

Comment: "There is no such thing as positively flagging" that is why I was suggesting a way to be able to accomplish the opposite and it is also why the last phrase of this post says: "I understand that flags are made for "negative" observations but I suggest new features to be able to give a positive feedback about an answer in addition to the up vote"

Comment: One thing I would say is I'm entirely for the idea of not having the accepted answer sort to the top, so the highest voted answer is always at the top - which would essentially achieve the same thing as you're suggesting - there's a feature request for that on MSE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in comments, the checkmark doesn't mean it is the best answer. It is the answer that was most helpful to the one asking the question.

Votes indicate the answer that is most useful to the community.

Flagging such questions is pointless and will always get refused because of this reason. Voting bad answers down and good ones up will make the good answers float to the top.

Comment: The title of the check mark says "The question owner accepted this as the best answer Dec 6 '08 at 10:40"

Comment: Yes, that's the opinion of the question  owner, not the community.

Comment: According to you is it pointless to have another feature whish says "10 users suggest this as the new best answer"?

Comment: Yes. I do. And I am sure this is the general opinion.

Comment: For your information I have just flagged my own question ;) Thanks for the patience

Comment: Why would you? There is no point in doing that and it only generates work for the moderators.

Comment: Because you made me realize it is pointless and I don't want to reach -5k votes it is humiliating

Comment: Don't mind. We've all been there and we are still alive.

Comment: Votes on meta doesn't affect rep in any way, so why does it matter? You posted a feature request, people didn't like it. No harm done IMHO. The next person who might consider suggesting it might find your post on the related tab, see that it didn't get traction and not post.

Comment: @Rafa flag only what is **absolutely essential**, else you can get flag-banned on meta/ main for too many declined flags..

Comment: Understood Ivarni and Infinite